# display all [TransactionID] where a customer purchased one pro and previously another one

Tags: sql

how to display all [TransactionID] where a customer purchased a
Hydration Packs and where their previous purchase — based on .[TransactionTimestamp] —
was either a Water Bottle or Cage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` window function as follows:

```
SELECT T.* FROM
(SELECT T.*, 
        LAG(ITEM_PURCHASED) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID 
                                  ORDER BY TransactionTimestamp) AS PREV_PURCHASE
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T) T
WHERE ITEM_PURCHASED = 'Hydration Packs' 
  AND PREV_PURCHASE IN ('Water Bottle', 'Cage')
```

I think you need `exists` as follows (as per your comment)

```
Select t.*
  From your_table t
 Where t.ITEM_PURCHASED = 'Hydration Packs' 
   And exists 
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where tt.CUSTOMER_ID = t.CUSTOMER_ID
           And tt.TransactionTimestamp < t.TransactionTimestamp
           And tt.ITEM_PURCHASED IN ('Water Bottle', 'Cage') )
```

Comment: As per this logic it is matching only based on immediate previous purchase. I am assuming that as per the question it need not be an immediate previous purchase. In other words, It can have a lag offset of 2,3,4,  ....

Comment: See the updated answer!!

Comment: Thanks for your crystal clear and simple solution.